# Vb.net creating report based on sql statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

Im new to vb and I want to make a report based on an sql statement. I can't quite find a tutorial with full explanation. Can anyone help me to find a tutorial or video

Comment: which reporting tool you are using?

Comment: @JigarPandya crystal report men.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Crystal Reports

For Beginners Find the link
[CrystalReport for Beginners](http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_step_by_step.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you can download the working source code of vb.net and crystal report from

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms227881%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Second you can check what are the basics of crystal report from

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142064/Step-by-Step-Creation-of-Crystal-Report-using-its
2. http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1055

Hope this help!